# Comments on deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page

Recently I gave a cryptical comment to an answer and I wanted to follow up and check whether the answer had been updated following my suggestion. It turned out I could not find my comment on my activity page. I could trace the question, by searching for it, and it turned out the answer had been deleted (a drastic consequence of my comment?). It was still visible but grayed out or so.

Isn't this a little strange, that comments are unlisted from the user page? I would expect them to stay, perhaps with a note that the answer or question was deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd guess it's a side effect of the fact that Stack Exchange considers comments second-class citizens: transient, liable to disappear at any time, not a priority for preserving, etc.

Or, it might be a side-effect of the fact that all deleted comments are treated the same way, and the primary way that comments can be deleted is for them to be deleted by a moderator or by their owner or for their parent post to be deleted by a moderator or by the community.  The situation where the owner of the parent post deletes their own post might have been viewed as secondary or unimportant or even overlooked.

This has been discussed on the main Meta; you can go there to vote for the corresponding feature requests, if you like:

- [My recently deleted comments should remain in the Comments view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216654/160917)
- [Add ability for all users to see their deleted comments within their profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198265/160917)